# BufferedReader still reads from a file even after the file have been deleted

Tags: java, kotlin, java-io

I run a small experiment trying to read a file using BufferedReader, and I wanted to see what would happen if I call the delete method on the file before the read is complete, and given that BufferedReader will only read a chunk of the file at a time I expected the operation to fail, but to my surprise the read was successful.

Here is the code I used:

```
val file = File("test.txt")

val bufferedReader = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(FileInputStream(file)), 1)

if (file.delete())
    println("file deleted successfully")

println(bufferedReader.readLines().size)
```

I used a relatively big file for the test with around 300mb of size, and I also set the buffer size to the minimum value possible, and the execution returns this:

```
file deleted successfully
1303692
```

Did I misunderstand something here? and could someone please explain this behavior?

The motivation behind this experiment is that I have a method in my application that returns a sequence of all lines in a temporary file, and I wanted to remove the temporary file once all lines were read like this:

```
fun getTempFileLines(): Sequence<String> {

    val file = File("temp.txt")
    val bufferedReader = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(FileInputStream(file)))

    val sequenceOfLines = generateSequence {
        bufferedReader.readLine()
    }

    file.delete()

    return sequenceOfLines
}
```

Comment: The filesystem entry is removed but the OS doesn't actually delete the file until everything that had it open at the time closes it.

Comment: Depends on your OS. For Linux/Mac OS your program can still access the file you deleted, until the program closes the file. But because it's deleted, you can't open it again after delete since it's gone from directory.

Comment: ... and that's why there are dozens if not hundreds of Qs across that last decade on several stacks all on the theme of "what happened to a lot of my disk space on Unix? df says it's allocated, but du doesn't show any files using it". A: deleted file(s) is(are) still open.

Comment: I am indeed using Linux, but I actually put a breakpoint right after delete() and verified if the file was actually deleted from the project directory and indeed It was. So is it just hidden or what happened to it? and would it be safe to rely on this behavior for my scenario?

Comment: This is how the Linux filesystem works, see https://access.redhat.com/solutions/2316 section "Root cause" for a more detailed explanation.

Answer (score -1):

From https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html

"Reads text from a character-input stream, buffering characters so as to provide for the efficient reading of characters, arrays, and lines."

So while the actual file may already be deleted, the bufferedReader still contains contents.

Comment: I would say the bufferedReader will only load a chunk of the content that will fill the buffer, that is why in my little experiment I used the minimum buffer size and a relatively big file to avoid the file being loaded at once into the buffer. but still the read succeeded

Comment: The `BufferedReader` still refers to an input stream from a file that still has contents. It may or may not have contents of its own. Doesn't address the real issue.